# How can I enable more GPUs in Ubuntu for poclbm?

Tags: ubuntu, poclbm, gpu

I have an Ubuntu set up (11.10) and 2 ATI Radeon HD 6870 cards. It detects one, but not the other for some reason when I try to run `poclbm`.

When I run `lspci`, it finds both cards.

Any help?

Comment: Try the command  display=:0  .

Comment: Maybe this is not going to help you, but... Ubuntu is a  distribution strongly oriented towards casual users, are you sure it's a wise choice to use it for mining? Couldn't you just use, for example, debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lspci` lists PCI devices. `./poclbm.py` lists OpenCL devices. If the former finds the device but the latter does not, your second GPU must not be registering as an OpenCL device.

Ubuntu 11.10 has a notorious reputation for multiple-GPU bugs. (See [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=53199.msg667050#msg667050) and [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=50388.msg601325#msg601325).) I personally have had issues with 11.10 mining that were resolved simply by switching to another release. I would suggest you instead use Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal); it is generally regarded to be the most reliable Ubuntu version for mining.

If that is not an option, or installing 11.04 doesn't fix the problem, try the following steps:

1. Uninstall whatever version of Catalyst/SDK you have (make sure to remove all configuration files) and install
   Catalyst 11.6 and SDK 2.4.
2. Run `aticonfig -f --initial --adapter=all` again. Make sure it runs without errors.
3. Run `aticonfig --list-adapters`. You should see two.

Those steps should fix any configuration issues. If your problem persists, it's either a hardware issue (or an Ubuntu 11.10 issue).

Answer (score -2):

Try not booting into graphical mode at all, just command line. Leaving compiz/gnome/gdm/drivers off should alleviate most confusion, as the cards should both be in default modes (and one in VESA/VGA) and for the most part will be untouched by system specifics (more like normal PCI devices)

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work; ATI OpenCL under Linux requires an X server running.